# Is there any native WPF Multiselect combobox available?

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpf-controls, multi-select

Even a 3rd party one will do.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no native multiselect combobox in WPF. Please check my blog for a simple hack using  expression blend to achieve a multi selection on combobox. 
http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2009/02/simple-multiselect-combobox-using.html
The idea is to utilize the Multi-Selection feature of ListBox in to ComboBox by editing the control template.

But for accessing the selected items you might need to use the bellow line in the code.

```
((ListBox)cmbBox.Template.FindName("lstBox",cmbBox)).SelectedItems
```

Where *cmbBox* is your combobox and *lstBox* is the ListBox inside the controltemaplate.

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure how a `ComboBox` would display data in this fashion, as it is designed as a single-selection Control.

Maybe you are looking for something like a `ListBox` or `ListView` with a `SelectionMode` of `Multiple` or `Extended`?

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" />

<ListBox SelectionMode="Extended" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I used an expander and filled the expander's header with the selection and the content with a list box. The list box is binded to a collection. Whenever user make a selection, I update the header to show what user has selected.

Answer (score 2):

I found this useful information from Codeproject - [ComboBoxMultiSelect](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45782/A-WPF-Combo-Box-with-Multiple-Selection)

I haven't tried it myself as of yet, but would let know about my experience.

Comment: [Link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/299295) is not a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is useful to anyone, I've made a rough and ready multi-select ComboBox.
Basically just a TextBlock with a Button, ListBox and a Popup. Easy to build upon I think.
Set to work with selections as list(of String), itemsSource as a list(of String), and raises a selectionsChanges event.

XAML: (user control with design dimensions excluded)

```
<Grid Margin="0,4,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="bdr" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtValues" MinWidth="50" Background="#F0F0F0" Margin="1,1,0,1" Padding="3,1,0,1">
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu><ContextMenu><MenuItem Header="Clear" Click="clearItems"/></ContextMenu></TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="showListBox">
        <Polygon Points="0,2 12,2 6,8" Fill="Black"/>
    </Button>
    <Popup x:Name="pop" StaysOpen="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=bdr}" Closed="pop_Closed">
        <ListBox x:Name="items" SelectionMode="Extended"
                 Width="{Binding ElementName=bdr,Path=ActualWidth}"/>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

and code..

```
Public Class multiCombo
Private _itemsSource As List(Of String)
Private _selections As List(Of String)
Public Event selectionsChanges(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Public Property selections As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return _selections
    End Get
    Set
        _selections = Value
        For Each itm In items.Items
            If Value.Contains(itm) Then
                If Not items.SelectedItems.Contains(itm) Then items.SelectedItems.Add(itm)
            Else
                If items.SelectedItems.Contains(itm) Then items.SelectedItems.Remove(itm)
            End If
        Next
        txtValues.Text = String.Empty
        For Each itm In Value
            If txtValues.Text.Length > 0 Then txtValues.Text += ", "
            txtValues.Text += itm
        Next
    End Set
End Property
Public Property itemsSource As List(Of String)
    Get
        Return _itemsSource
    End Get
    Set
        _itemsSource = Value
        items.ItemsSource = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private Sub showListBox(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    pop.IsOpen = True
End Sub
Private Sub pop_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim changed = items.SelectedItems.Count <> selections.Count
    If Not changed Then
        For Each selItm In items.SelectedItems
            If Not selections.Contains(selItm) Then changed = True
        Next
    End If
    If changed Then
        selections.Clear()
        txtValues.Text = String.Empty
        For Each selItm In items.SelectedItems
            selections.Add(selItm)
            If txtValues.Text.Length > 0 Then txtValues.Text += ", "
            txtValues.Text += selItm
        Next
        RaiseEvent selectionsChanges(Me, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub clearItems(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If selections.Count > 0 Then
        selections.Clear()
        txtValues.Text = String.Empty
        items.SelectedItems.Clear()
        RaiseEvent selectionsChanges(Me, Nothing)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a long time ago but came across this and figured I'd drop a more up-to-date answers.

You can use a `ComboBox` with checkbox templates.  For Example:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"></CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Another CodeProject with detailed explanations how to create a ComboBox with multiple selectable Checkboxes:
[Multi Select ComboBox in WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF)

Comment: [Link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/299295) is not a good answer.