# Selecting and Deleting Multiple Items in a Combobox

Tags: c#, combobox

I am building a Window 10 app which includes a combobox that has been populated with several items obtained from an IList object.

When the user opens/expands the combobox, they should be able to select one or more items, by holding them down for more than a certain interval, say of 1 second, so that they can delete them by clicking a button.

How could this multiple selection and the interval be achieved?

Comment: UWP? WPF? First question could be this [WPF multi-selection ComboBox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/508506/1997232), second question is unclear ("holding whom down"? what is *holding*?).

Comment: I am using UWP. But let's forget about multi-selection for now. When the user opens/expands the combobox, I want them to hold down (the way a key is held down for a prolonged interval to distinguish it from a click) an item and a dialog box to appear asking them if they want the item deleted. Through which event could I achieve this?