# ComboBox with fixed Header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I need to show a default text in my `ComboBox`, this text must not changed also when the user select an item of the `Combobox`, actually for do this I've created this structure:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableNations}" Width="160" Height="55" Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" 
           Text="Select Countries" IsEditable="True">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Item.Name}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

this display as default text `Select Countries` but if I select an item the default text will disappear and the item selected will be displayed, how can I fix this?

Comment: `ComboBox` is intended to display selected item. Why don't you show `"Select country:"` next to it using `TextBlock`? Why it has to be a part of `ComboBox`? Normally this behavior (to display hint) is used when `ComboBox` doesn't have any selection. But as soon as it have one the hint is not needed anymore and selected value is displayed.

Comment: 'cause I need to display a default text in combobox not the selected item, the user could select more items in my combobox..

Comment: You can set `Text` to `"Select Countries"` after selection is processed (I assume what you display that multi-selection to the user somehow, having to open dropdown to see it doesn't sounds like a good design). Have you tried to look for existing multi-selection `ComboBox`es? E.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/508506/1997232).

Comment: I wrote my own class to manage multi selection

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that you want the text to display `Select Countries  :` when blank, and something like `Select Countries : CAN, US, ETC` when item(s) are selected?

Comment: @Rachel nope, the value displayed should be even `Select Countries`. I've a list of checkboxes inside the combobox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Combined Template ([ref post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2277488/4838058))

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalItemTemplate" >
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Item.Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SelectionBoxTemplate" >
            <TextBlock>Select Countries</TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CombinedTemplate">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
                   Content="{Binding}"
                   ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NormalItemTemplate}" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,ComboBoxItem,1}}"
                        Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="ContentTemplate"
                            Value="{StaticResource SelectionBoxTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableNations}"                  
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNation}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CombinedTemplate}"
              Width="160" Height="55" Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" >
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

The way it works is described in the original answer. Note that the suggested solution will only work when IsEditable is set to false, I assume that won't be a problem in your case. Second, to get the text displayed at start up I bound SelectedItem (e.g. to the first item in the collection).

Answer (score 2):

From the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390123/combobox-with-fixed-header#comment66116096_39390123), it sounds like you just want the `Select Countries` text to display at all times, even when an item is selected.

Personally I would just go the simple route and place a `TextBox` on top of the `ComboBox`, and hide the Display Text of the ComboBox by using a Transparent Foreground color.

Here's a quick example demonstrating it :

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="1" Foreground="Transparent">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <!-- Make sure ComboBoxItems don't have transparent text -->
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
        <ComboBoxItem>Test 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Test 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Test 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>

    <TextBlock Text="Select Countries" Margin="4,3" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
</Grid>
```

And the results (note that `SelectedIndex = 1`)

[image]

I'm sure there's other ways too, such as overwriting the way it paints the display text, or changing the control template, but this seemed like the easiest to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've appreciated +1