# Disable combobox closing when select item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have `ComboBox` with custom `ComboBoxItem`. `ComboBoxItem` contains `TextBlock` and `CheckBox`. `CheckBox` bind to bool property in my ViewModel. When i click to `CheckBox`, all works fine, but when i click to `TextBlock` - `ComboBox` Closing! I need 'MultiSelection' mode inside my `ComboBox`

xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

VM:

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string m_caption;
    private bool m_isSelected;

    public string Caption
    {
        get { return m_caption; }
        set
        {
            if (m_caption != value)
            {
                m_caption = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Caption");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return m_isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (m_isSelected != value)
            {
                m_isSelected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    public SomeClass(string _caption)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_caption))
            m_caption = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Caption = _caption;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string _property)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler hanlder = PropertyChanged;
        if (hanlder != null)
        {
            hanlder.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_property));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `picture` or maybe some `code` is worth more than a thousand `word`s.

Comment: @CodeCaster updated

Comment: You should first integrate your text into `CheckBox.Content` instead of using a separate `TextBlock`. This will allow you to click the text and trigger the Checkbox with it. It won't solve the whole thing, but its a good starting point

Comment: @grek40 What i shall do, if my "custom" combobox item has more complex view?

Comment: `ComboBox.Content` is quite universally applicable, you can nest a whole bunch of controls in it. As said - its the starting point to capture mouse clicks inside the content to count towards the CheckBox rather than the surrounding ComboBoxItem

Comment: I think you want something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508506/is-there-any-native-wpf-multiselect-combobox-available or http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1a81c5/multi-select-combobox-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a lot of tweaking, you can't really display a multi-selection in a closed combobox, so I guess this part is not really needed. So I propose you use a button and a popup, where the popup is containing a listview with multi selection enabled for your items.

As Button, I use `DropDownButton` from Extended WPF Toolkit, you can also implement it differently.

Introducing the Extended WPF Toolkit namespace:

```
xmlns:xt="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

The actual thing:

```
<xt:DropDownButton Content="Elements Selection" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="100">
    <xt:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" SelectionMode="Multiple" MinWidth="100">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}">
                        <CheckBox.Content>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}"/>
                        </CheckBox.Content>
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </xt:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
</xt:DropDownButton>
```

Another important little detail to reflect the property changes in WPF: your property changed notifications need a source instead of `null`!

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string _property)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(_property));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `Content` property of the `CheckBox` to your `Caption` property and use an `ItemContainerStyle` that stretches the `ComboBoxItem` container:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      Content="{Binding Caption}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```